# Finding index of multiple variation of a string

Tags: python, list, indexing

I need to get the index of first name and account number of a csv file.

so some files might look like this

```
data = ['account number', 'first name']
or
data = ['account #', 'First Name']
or
data = ['ACCOUNT NUMBER', 'FIRST NAME'] etc.
or
data = ['...',.....,'account num',...,'firstname']
```

So from what I found so far([sackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python)), i can use `l.index('first name')` to get the index. Also reading the def([python tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_index.htm)) it seem to take only one parameter.

Any idea how I can check for index if it's any of those?

Comment: An overflowing sack reminds me of xmas :)

Comment: Can you explain more about your problem? maybe an expected output could help!

Comment: Does each CSV file have the field names on the first line of the file?

Comment: so I want the able to do something like data.index(['first name', 'FIRST NAME, 'firstname', 'First Name']) and get the index. So in first 3 i would get an index of 1, where in the fourth list i may get an index of i lets say for the sake of a value 4. and yes, the first line is all the headers of the csv file

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
idx = [i for i, item in enumerate(data) if item.lower() == 'first name']
```

or more generally:

```
alist = ['first name', 'first name'] ## or ['account number', 'account #', ...]
idx = [i for i, item in enumerate(data) if item.lower() in alist]
```

You can also use regular expressions for more complex cases:

```
import re
idx = [i for i, item in enumerate(data) if re.search(pattern, item)]
```

Comment: what about account number where it might say 'account #' maybe can throw in or condition in there? if thats possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.match` within a list comprehension :

```
import re
indices = [i for i,s in enumerate(data) if re.match(r'^(account.*)|(first\s?name)$',s,re.I)]
```

The following regex :

```
r'^(account.*)|(first\s?name)$
```

will match any string that start with `account` or any string that start with `first` and an optional whitespace then `name` also it has a `Ignorecase` flag to ignore of the case of your string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, using sets. If no string matches the options for a field, then -1 is returned for its index, similar to `str.find()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

accnums = set(['account number', 'account #', 'account num', 'accnum'])
firstnames = set(['first name', 'firstname', '1stname'])

def find_fields(seq):
    accnum, firstname = (-1, -1)
    for i, field in enumerate(seq):
        field = field.lower()
        if field in accnums:
            accnum = i
        elif field in firstnames:
            firstname = i
    return accnum, firstname

testdata = [
    ['account number', 'first name'],
    ['account #', 'First Name'],
    ['ACCOUNT NUMBER', 'FIRST NAME'],
    ['accnum', '1stname'],
    ['country', 'lastname', 'account num', 'account type', 'firstname'],
    ['accnum', '1stname', 'account #'],
    ['albatross', 'first name'],
    ['Account Number', 'duck'],
]

for data in testdata:
    print data, find_fields(data)
```

**output**

```
['account number', 'first name'] (0, 1)
['account #', 'First Name'] (0, 1)
['ACCOUNT NUMBER', 'FIRST NAME'] (0, 1)
['accnum', '1stname'] (0, 1)
['country', 'lastname', 'account num', 'account type', 'firstname'] (2, 4)
['accnum', '1stname', 'account #'] (2, 1)
['albatross', 'first name'] (-1, 1)
['Account Number', 'duck'] (0, -1)
```

Note that if it finds multiple matching entries for a field it returns the index of the *last* matching field. Thus for `['accnum', '1stname', 'account #']` it returns 2 as the index for the account number field.

You can expand the `if: ... elif:` block in `find_fields()` to handle more fields with varying names, but if you have a lot of these fields then it would be better to modify the logic so that it's working with a list of sets rather than with individual sets.